# using mirth connect to receive HL7 messages from Meditech and save into azure db

Tags: azure-sql-database, real-time, hl7, mirth-connect

1. Can Mirth connect listen to HL7 messages coming from Meditech via TCP/IP? (is this real-time?)
2. If yes, and once received can it parse and mapp fields to save into azure sql server database?
3. mirth connect vs. develop own engine using HAPI and deploy on azure cloud that can receive HL7 via TCP/IP and save into database. Which one is cost-effective or better in terms of automating the process?

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes. It is real time. Mirth Connect implements LLP listeners for HL7 messages
2. Yes. You will have to implement mappings in Mirth Connect to map the messages to your own database structure. You should search the [Mirth Forums](http://www.mirthcorp.com/community/forums/) for details on connecting to Azure. I recall there being some extra things you have to pass to JDBC to connect to Azure. You should note that Mirth Connect itself runs on a database, the database that MC uses for its own message management is not the same one you would map messages to for your use case.
3. Mirth Connect is more cost effective. With Mirth Connect you get message logging, queuing, error handling, connection management, thread management, and other features for free. You can write these yourself but why bother when it is already there. This lets you focus on the real work of mapping your Meditech HL7 messages to your database for your project. The overhead of logging and monitoring and management is already done.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It all makes sense. One last question, can mirth manage multiple tcp/ip connections (different vendors) that connects to my local port to receive HL7 messages?

Comment: Yes. Generally you'd use one channel per vendor. Common mappings would then be in another channel or code templates